# minikube cluster pods are unhealthy and restarting because of connection refused error

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I have installed minikube cluster on centos7 VM. After installation, few pods are restarting because of unhealthy pod status. all failed pods have similar reasons:

[image]

Error from pods (describe command):

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.4:6789/readyz": dial tcp 172.17.0.4:6789: connect: connection refused

Liveness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.4:6789/healthz": dial tcp 172.17.0.4:6789: connect: connection refused

Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

Because of these errors, application in the pod is not working properly.
I am new to kubernates and not able to understand to debug this error

**UPDATE** please see below the error logs of pod(che-operator)

```
time="2021-09-09T15:37:13Z" level=info msg="Deployment plugin-registry is in the rolling update state."
I0909 15:37:15.651964 1 request.go:655] Throttling request took 1.04725976s, request: GET:https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/extensions/v1beta1?timeout=32s
time="2021-09-09T15:37:16Z" level=info msg="Deployment plugin-registry is in the rolling update state."
I0909 15:37:37.710602 1 request.go:655] Throttling request took 1.046990691s, request: GET:https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
W0909 15:43:23.172829 1 warnings.go:70] extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
E0909 15:47:05.403189 1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock eclipse-che/e79b08a4.org.eclipse.che: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/eclipse-che/configmaps/e79b08a4.org.eclipse.che": context deadline exceeded
I0909 15:47:05.403334 1 leaderelection.go:278] failed to renew lease eclipse-che/e79b08a4.org.eclipse.che: timed out waiting for the condition
{"level":"info","ts":1631202425.4036877,"logger":"controller","msg":"Stopping workers","reconcilerGroup":"org.eclipse.che","reconcilerKind":"CheCluster","controller":"checluster"}
{"level":"error","ts":1631202425.4034257,"logger":"setup","msg":"problem running manager","error":"leader election lost","stacktrace":"github.com/go-logr/zapr.(*zapLogger).Error\n\t/che-operator/vendor/github.com/go-logr/zapr/zapr.go:132\nmain.main\n\t/che-operator/main.go:254\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/proc.go:204"}
```

Comment: Could you provide a way of reproducing this error ? It would be best to see the exact steps that you've taken so far. How exactly have you installed your **Minikube** ? Did you try to run anything else on it like simple nginx pod before trying to install eclipse-che ?

Comment: mkdir kube
cd kube
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
chmod u+x kubectl
minikube start --addons=ingress --vm=true --memory=8192 --driver=none
minikube kubectl – get po -A
chectl server:deploy --platform minikube

Comment: Do you know how to disable leader election on operator pod

Comment: Unfortunately can't help you with this, is it somehow related with the main issue ? Maybe you've already managed to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your readiness and Live ness probe failing based on error

> Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.4:6789/readyz"

Readiness & liveness probe use to check the status of application inside the POD. It continuously check the application status on one endpoint if application fail to responded Kubernetes will restart your POD automatically.

In this case I would suggest checking your application status running inside the POD. readyz & health failing due to this your pods are failing.

Read more about the Readiness & liveness at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

You can also check the log of application using :

```
kubectl get logs <POD name>
```

Comment: Do you know how to disable leader election on operator pod